# Problem with FAT32 filesystem, need to install dosfstools and mtools

Tags: apt, filesystem, dependencies, gparted, fat32

In my HDD I was trying to convert a filesystem from FAT32 to NTFS with gparted, but I cannot see my HDD.  Gparted shows me HDD (/dev/sda2) but it shows this message:

[image: Gparted screenshot]

I am trying to install mtools and dosfstools packages, but I have unmet dependencies that I am not able to fix.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to convert file systems and the warning message and the underlying problem that triggered it have nothing to do with file systems directly. It may have to do with dynamic disks, a Microsoft proprietary technology, or logical and/or physical errors on the drive.

You can remove the entire partition and create another one in its place with the desired file system. If, however, there are data to be recovered from there, then please connect it to a Windows OS for error corrections and/or backup.

Comment: My converting try was to create new partition with NTFS filesystem beside FAT32, then remove it and to expand new NTFS partition. This for not formatting and deleting my files in HDD. After restart my PC I had that bad surprise..   are you sure that deleting it is the only one solution?

Comment: Agter analyze and repair in Wdows OS, this is gparted result:  http://imgur.com/a/Lpqzp

Comment: If I have to delete that partition and to create brand new one, what is better? NTFS? Ext4?

Comment: Thanx for all, but I have to access to that HDD with Ubuntu and Wdows. I'd create a NTFS partition..